# Tryingto import in js and keeps getting "AddEventListener" is not defined. even though its defined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, import, export

I have two JS files that is script and au-script. I`m trying to import functions and array from au-script to script.

When I open the html connected to script.js, I get an error called
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
at au-script.js:7:12"
I`m not 100% right but I think the html connected with script.js is trying to find the addEventListener.

au-script.js code

```
let userName = document.getElementById("name")
let nameValue;
let userNum;
let newInfo = [];
const getNameBtn = document.getElementById("getNameBtn");

getNameBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    randomNumber()  
    getName()
    console.log(newInfo[newInfo.length - 1].name)
})

function getName() {
nameValue = userName.value;
document.getElementById("showName").textContent = nameValue

    if (nameValue) {
        newInfo.push({ name:nameValue }, { user: userNum})  
    } else {
        alert("名前を入力してください")
    }
}

function randomNumber() {
    let getRandomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20000) + 10000
    userNum = getRandomNum
}


    export {newInfo, getName, randomNumber}
```

script.js

```
    import {
    newInfo, getName, randomNumber} from "./2nd-page/au-script.js";


const getNumber = document.getElementById("number");
const getValueBtn = document.getElementById("getValueBtn")

let getValueNumber
getValueBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    getValueNumber = getNumber.value
    findE()
    console.log(employees)
    addNewUser()
})

let employees = [{
    user: "20001",
    name:"レイン",
    workDays:"20" + "Days",
}, {
    user: "20002",
    name:"アモルファスカーボン",
    workDays: "21" + "Days"
}]

function addNewUser() {
    employees.push(newInfo)
}


function findE() {
    const findUser = employees.find(u => u.user == getValueNumber)
    if (findUser) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = findUser.name
        document.getElementById("workDays").innerHTML = findUser.workDays
    } else {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "登録されていません"
        document.getElementById("workDays").innerHTML = "登録されていません"
    }
    console.log(findUser)
}
```

index.html connected with script.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <h1>タイムカードシステム</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="作業員番号を入力してください"/>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-container">
        <button id="getValueBtn">エンター</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="userInfo">
        名前:<p id="name"></p>
        出勤日数:<p id="workDays"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="pages-container">
        <p></p>
        <a href="/2nd-page/adduser.html">"新し作業員を登録する"</a>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="script.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

adduser.html connected with au-script.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/2nd-page/au-style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-container">
        <h1>登録と削除システム</h1>
        <p>新し作業員を登録する</p>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="名前を入力してください"/>

        <button id="getNameBtn">登録する</button>
    </div>

    <div class="userInfo">
        名前:<p id="showName"></p>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="/2nd-page/au-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can't see where `getNameBtn` is defined - `the html connected with script.js` huh? there's no HTML in your question ... also, that error occurs on line 7 according to you, did you miss some code in the question, because `addEventListener` is on line 2

Comment: The error message tells you `getNameBtn` is not defined.

Comment: Im sorry!, I just fixed it now and put all of the code.